# Possible to query local DB for data to use for tests instead of fixtures?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, fixtures, django-testing, django-tests

I am hoping there is a way this can be done...but so far I have not been able to find a solution...

I have unit tests + functional tests setup in Django. The unit tests are using TestCase and my functional tests are using LiveServerTestCase. Both from Django.test.

In both instances I want to load in a bunch of data from my local db first (via ORM), to use during the tests.

I have these queries in the setUp() methods, because I thought at that point you can still query your local db. But whenever I run the queries it returns 0 results. I have a feeling this is because it's querying my test database already, and not my actual local db (I can get results when performing these queries outside of my tests / the query logic is fine).

I know you can use fixtures...but that seems like a pain...I'd ideally like to have my dynamic queries run and grab the data from my local db pre-test, then use that data within my tests.

Thoughts?